# rails server stating your ruby version is 2.7.0 but your gemfile is 3.0.2 in linux

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am not able to figure out why is this happening. I have tried doing rvm install "ruby-3.0.2" but it is giving error. HOW CAN I MAKE THIS "rails serve"

Comment: What is in your .ruby-version file?

Comment: "ruby-3.0.2" this is... please help me

Comment: if i change over there in .ruby-version file..Traceback (most recent call last) this error comes up

Comment: Which ruby version do you actually want? Either set the ruby version to 2.7.0 in .ruby-version.rb file or change the version of ruby you are running in the server to use 3.0.2 instead of 2.7.0, `rvm use 3.0.2@some_gemset` is possibly what you are looking for?

Comment: Copy & paste the output of the command `rvm list`

Comment: sirs , i got it fixed thank you